# Data tip customization in matlab figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a graph with several plots, each of them comes from a different source file. I want the data tip to tell me (X,Y) plus the name of the source file. So long my best try (without success) is this:

```
dcm = datacursormode(gcf);
datacursormode on;
set(dcm,'UpdateFcn',[@myfunction,{SourceFileName}]);
```

Where *myfunction* is the default function used in this cases, as pasted at the end of this message and as explained here:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/
Finally, SourceFileName is a string with the name of the source file.

Does anybody knows an easier (or correct) way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
function output_txt = myfunction(~,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p=plot( x,y);
setappdata(p,'sourceFile_whatever', SourceFileName)  

dcm = datacursormode(gcf);
datacursormode on;
set(dcm, 'updatefcn', @myfunction)
```

and in callback function:

```
function output_txt = myfunction( obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).
% event_obj

dataIndex = get(event_obj,'DataIndex');
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');

output_txt = {[ 'X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

try
    p=get(event_obj,'Target');
    output_txt{end+1} = ['SourceFileName: ',getappdata(p,'sourceFile_whatever')];
end


% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the game, but I thought I would answer in case anyone comes across this question and still finds it useful.

Change

```
set(dcm,'UpdateFcn',[@myfunction,{SourceFileName}]);
```

to

```
set(dcm,'UpdateFcn',{@myfunction,SourceFileName});
```

Then the callback function can be changed to something like the following. (Note: I removed the Z coordinate because the question mentioned only X and Y.)

```
function output_txt = myfunction(~,event_obj,filename)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% filename     Name of the source file (string)
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)],...
    ['Source: ',filename]};

end
```

Obviously you can do anything you want with the formatting inside the callback function in case you want the string in a different format.

You can add any number of arguments to the callback function simply by changing its function signature and updating the `set(dcm,...` line to match (additional arguments go inside the `{}`, separated by commas).  This works for R2013a (and I assume later), but I have not tried it on any earlier versions.

EDIT: The callback function may also need to be defined in the same file as the code that uses it.