# Adding extra information to datapoints on a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

THERE IS THE SOLUTION BELOW!

[image]

This (x,y) value actually corresponds to a t value, which I want to see on the plot. What can I do?

Clearly matlab has the ability to display multiple information in the datapoint box:

[image]
just call it as "TimePlot(x,y,t)" and it will work. This code, I believe, also illustrates a few key points in modifying datatips.

```js
function  TimePlot( varargin )
x=varargin{1};
y=varargin{2};
t=varargin{nargin};
fh=figure;
plot(varargin{1:nargin-1})

function output_txt = myfunction(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).




pos = get(event_obj,'Position');

ind=intersect(Find(x,pos(1),1e-10),Find(y,pos(2),1e-10));
if(length(ind)~=1)
    text='err';
else
    text=num2str(t(ind),4);
end

output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)],['T: ',text]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if (length(pos) > 2)
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end

end

dcm=datacursormode(fh);
datacursormode on
set(dcm,'updatefcn',@myfunction)



end

function [ out ] = Find( vector, value ,precision)

if nargin < 3
    precision =   0.0001;
end

out=[];

for i=1:length(vector)
    
    if(abs(vector(i)-value)<precision)
        out=[out i];
    end

end

end
```

Comment: Please be more specific on how you want to accomplish this.  If you have a more specific coding question, edit your question.  Otherwise it is off topic for StackOverflow (you might instead be able to get help on SuperUser)

Comment: [**Here is a tutorial on how to do this**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/).

Comment: or cunsult this duplicate question [Data tip customization in matlab figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100086/data-tip-customization-in-matlab-figure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MATLAB Central you can find an extensive video tutorial on how to create custom data tips: [**Tutorial: How to make a custom data tip in MATLAB**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/).

> If you use the standard data tip in MATLAB, it will annotate the X and Y value of a data point. This video will show how to customize the information that is shown in that data tip.

In the [**documentation about the datacursormode**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) you find some more examples  (the following all copied from doc):

> This example enables data cursor mode on the current figure and sets
>   data cursor mode options. The following statements
>
> - Create a graph
> - Toggle data cursor mode to on
> - Obtain the data cursor mode object, specify data tip options, and get the handle of the line the data tip occupies:

```
fig = figure;
z = peaks;
plot(z(:,30:35))
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
set(dcm_obj,'DisplayStyle','datatip',...
    'SnapToDataVertex','off','Enable','on')

disp('Click line to display a data tip, then press Return.')
% Wait while the user does this.
pause 

c_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
% Make selected line wider
set(c_info.Target,'LineWidth',2)
```

[image]

> This example shows you how to customize the text that the data cursor
>   displays. For example, you can replace the text displayed in the data
>   tip and data window (x: and y:) with Time: and Amplitude: by creating
>   a simple update function.
>
> Save the following functions in your current directory or any writable
>   directory on the MATLAB path before running them. As they are
>   functions, you cannot highlight them and then evaluate the selection
>   to make them work.
>
> Save this code as doc_datacursormode.m:

```
function doc_datacursormode % Plots graph and sets up a custom data tip update function 
fig = figure; 
a = -16; 
t = 0:60; 
plot(t,sin(a*t)) 
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig); 
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)
```

> Save the following code as myupdatefcn.m on the MATLAB path:

```
function txt = myupdatefcn(empt,event_obj) % Customizes text of data tips

pos = get(event_obj,'Position'); txt = {['Time: ',num2str(pos(1))],...
          ['Amplitude: ',num2str(pos(2))]};
```

> To set up and use the update function, type:

```
doc_datacursormode
```

> When you place a data tip using this update function, it looks like
>   the one in the following figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can see the value of third dimension in a two dimensional plot. Can you try doing surf(x,y,t) or plot3(x,y,t) so that you get a three dimensional plot and with proper orientation you can get required plot and all the required x, y and t values.