# How to add labels on each line and add 2nd y-axes to the right side of the 'loglog' plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, iso, loglog

Recently I am trying to implement the ISO classification for the roadway assessment. Please refer to the paper [The use of vehicle acceleration measurements to estimate road roughness](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00423110701485050). But I bumped into some questions about plotting the ISO classification graph. The code is shown as follows:

```
%% generate ISO Clasification Curve (m^2/(rad/m))
AngSpaFre = 10^(-3):0.01:10^2;                                  % spatial frequency (rad/m)
ParamTable = [0              1*10^(-6)       2*(10^(-6));       % ISO classification parameters
              2*(10^(-6))    4*(10^(-6))     8*(10^(-6));       % (lower bound, geometric average, upper bound)
              8*(10^(-6))    16*(10^(-6))    32*(10^(-6));
              32*(10^(-6))   64*(10^(-6))    128*(10^(-6));
              128*(10^(-6))  256*(10^(-6))   512*(10^(-6));
              512*(10^(-6))  1024*(10^(-6))  2048*(10^(-6));
              2048*(10^(-6)) 4096*(10^(-6))  8192*(10^(-6));
              8192*(10^(-6)) 16384*(10^(-6)) 32768*(10^(-6))];
class_num = 8;
len = length(AngSpaFre);
iso_table = zeros(class_num, len);
for i = 1:class_num
  geo_mean = ParamTable(i, 2);
  geo_upbound = ParamTable(i, 3);
  for j = 1:len
    if(AngSpaFre(j) <= 1)
        iso_table(i,j) = geo_mean*(AngSpaFre(j)^(-2));
    else
        iso_table(i,j) = geo_mean*(AngSpaFre(j)^(-1.5));
    end
  end
end

figure,
ht = loglog(AngSpaFre, iso_table(1,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(2,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(3,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(4,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(5,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(6,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(7,:), AngSpaFre, iso_table(8,:));
hY = get(gca,'ylim');
hold on;
loglog([1 1], hY);
xlabel('Spatial Frequency \Omega (rad/m)');
ylabel('PSD (m^2/(rad/m))'); 
title('ISO Classification (log-log scale)');
```

And the current result is illustrated as the figure bellow:
[image]

Then 2 questions comes in my implementation and hope any one could give me some solutions or simple examples to make the problems clear.

**Q1:** Since the classification curve should recognize the quality-level of a road. So I'd like to add labels below each line to indicate the level like the graph below. How can I realize this in matlab? 
[image: ISO classification with labels]

**Q2:** Also, I'd like to add another y-axis on the right-side of the 'loglog' plot without log-scale values like the figure below. How to achieve this? I've refer to many examples in official website but most focus on the 'plot'/'plotyy' examples. :(
[image: ISO classification with 2nd y-axis without log-scale values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer Part I

The common way to put text somewhere is the [**annotation**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) function. It's quite hard do get it right with its basic functions, so rather use it with the **latex interpreter** as it allows you to specify the gap between every line with `'\vspace{gapwidth}'` and a lot [**more options**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotationtextbox-properties.html):

```
strings = {'H','G','F','E','D','C','B','A'};
verticalspace = '\vspace{4pt}';
str = cellfun(@(x) [x verticalspace],strings,'uni',0);


annotation('textbox', [0.4,0.6,0.1,0.1],...
           'String', str,...
           'LineStyle','none','Interpreter','latex');
```

[image]

It's definitely fiddly and you should use a fixed figure width.

An alternative is to use [**custom datatips**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468035/adding-extra-information-to-datapoints-on-a-plot/30468804#30468804) and tweak them as desired. Advantage is that the position of the textbox is relative to your data and not figure.

My general recommendation: **don't use Matlab at all for doing such tweaking**, it's pain in the a... . Save your figure as pdf (`set(gcf,'renderer','painters')`) and do the post processing with any vector graphics program or directly with LaTeX/Tikz.

### Answer Part II

To get a second axes, use:

```
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'Color','none');
ax2.YAxisLocation = 'right';
ax2.YLim = [0, 120];
ax2.YTick = 0:10:120;
ax2.XTick = [];
```

And again, specify the exact figure dimensions before! Resizing afterwards just makes troubles.

[image]

### Summary

All together underneath your current code:

```
%%
f = gcf;
f.Units = 'pixels';
f.Position = ([100,100,1000,800]);

%%
strings = {'H','G','F','E','D','C','B','A'};
verticalspace = '\vspace{7.6pt}';
str = cellfun(@(x) [x verticalspace],strings,'uni',0);

annotation('textbox', [0.4,0.61,0.1,0.1],...
           'String', str,...
           'LineStyle','none','Interpreter','latex');

%%
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'Color','none');
ax2.YAxisLocation = 'right';
ax2.YLim = [0, 120];
ax2.YTick = 0:10:120;
ax2.XTick = [];
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x')
```

would give (not resized):

[image]